# whats difference between pandas.HDFStore.select and pandas.HDFStore.get

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

There are two functions to read HDF files in pandas [get](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.select.html) and [select](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.select.html). It seems both of them do the same "Retrieve pandas object stored in file," but what is the difference?

It is obvious that [select](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.select.html) accepts more parameters, but if one specifies only the `key` argument, it will act precisely as [get](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.select.html).

one idea is that [get](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.select.html) may run faster (because it checks fewer conditions), but this idea is not correct:

```
print(timeit(lambda: dataset.hdf_store.select('/D/ADMG23202002101011'),number=100))
print(timeit(lambda: dataset.hdf_store.get('/D/ADMG23202002101011'),number=100))
0.6269406000001254
0.7711359369995989
```

another hypothesis is that maybe [select](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.select.html) uses [get](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.get.html) inside itself, but its not even correct due to its [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.1/pandas/io/pytables.py#L781-L875)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the case, but maybe they are two different interfaces that came in two different times and they are still there because of backward compatibility for old code bases.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary both of them are available in pandas 1.0 [select](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.select.html) and [get](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.get.html)

Comment: As you noted, usually when an interface takes more parameters it gives you more flexibility but less performance because of several checks. I think only Pandas developers can answer this.